# Triggering tasks and running programs when Windows 7 is plugged in or unplugged?

Tags: power-management, services, windows-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to execute a program on power events?](https://superuser.com/questions/121045/is-there-a-way-to-execute-a-program-on-power-events)

**Is there a Windows event** that I can watch in Task Scheduler that will trigger when the power is plugged in?  And an event when the power is unplugged?

I want to start and stop CrashPlan while on battery power. (This has been a [2.5-year-old feature request](https://crashplan.zendesk.com/entries/65387-stop-crashplan-when-using-battery-power) in CrashPlan and honestly I can't wait for them to add it.)

Others have also asked previously how to disable [SuperFetch](https://superuser.com/questions/338752/how-can-i-disable-superfetch-when-running-windows-7-on-battery-power) and [Search Indexing](https://superuser.com/questions/60508/how-do-i-disable-windows-search-indexing-service-while-on-battery-on-windows-7) on battery power. I think this trick will solve these questions, too.

Is there such a windows event?  If not, could there be a program that I can install that detects power changes, which then I can create a Task Scheduler trigger for.

Answer (score 4):

**By default, Windows does not log an event when you unplug or plug in your computer.**

However, with PowerShell you can listen for such a change and write your own events to the log. This script will do that:

```
New-EventLog -Source BatteryStatusMonitor -LogName Application

Function OnBatteryStatusChange ($NewStatus) {
  If ($NewStatus -eq 1) {
    $EventID = 5001
    $Message = "The computer was unplugged."
  } ElseIf ($NewStatus -eq 2) {
    $EventID = 5002
    $Message = "The computer was plugged in."
  } Else {
    $EventID = 5000
    $Message = "Battery status changed to $NewStatus"
  }
  Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source BatteryStatusMonitor -EventID $EventID -Message $Message
}

$Query = "select * from __instancemodificationevent within 3 where targetinstance isa 'win32_battery' and targetinstance.batterystatus <> previousinstance.batterystatus"

Register-WmiEvent -Query $Query -Action {OnBatteryStatusChange $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.BatteryStatus} -SourceIdentifier "BatteryStatusChange"

For (;;) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in supporting Windows Vista and above, [register for power events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373195.aspx).

Use [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373196.aspx) with the GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE value.

Comment: If the only event OP wants to capture is a change in the AC charger status through the Win32 API, he can simply handle PBT_APMPOWERSTATUSCHANGE events through the SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT control code in the HandlerEx callback to RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx, or the WM_POWERBROADCAST message in WindowProc. This should be supported by Windows XP and later. However, he asked for an Windows Event.