# Can I detect when the power went out/came back on with my windows 7 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, power

my office is having some power problems, and I was wondering if there is anything in windows 7 (or software anyone could recommend) that would help monitor the power fluctuations.    I have a windows 7 thinkpad (t400) plugged in perpetually - is there any way to see the history of when it switched from plug to battery and back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question was actually already answered here [Triggering tasks and running programs when Windows 7 is plugged in or unplugged?](https://superuser.com/questions/389689/triggering-tasks-and-running-programs-when-windows-7-is-plugged-in-or-unplugged) if you read the answer that states what the situation is, and what kind of solution you can use for your situation.  Note, your question isn't a duplicate of *that* question, it is just that your question is *answered* there.

Or, you could just set the laptop to Sleep after 1 minute of being on battery, and then later look through the logs for **event ID 42 in System log from source Kernel-Power** as that would be a Sleep event.

Answer (score 0):

[See if this software does the trick](http://exodusdev.com/products/monitor-win32-power-management-events), unfortunately it does not log anything, so if the PC shuts down, sleeps or hibernates, the broadcast events will be lost.

.

[image]