# Powershell script hogging CPU resources

Tags: windows-7, event-log

My computer is a HP laptop running Windows 7 64-bit. A Google search looking for a solution to generate an event in the eventlog any time I switch from AC to battery or vice versa, landed me to:

[Triggering tasks and running programs when Windows 7 is plugged in or unplugged?](https://superuser.com/questions/389689/triggering-tasks-and-running-programs-when-windows-7-is-plugged-in-or-unplugged/389853#389853)

While the Powershell script provided at the link above works, it uses up 25% of CPU resources and that is too much for me. Is there a better way?

The goal is to use the event generating script with Task Scheduler to open Windows Mobility center when I switch power states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `Start-Sleep -s 10` in the script - maybe inside this weird looking for loop, or somewhere else.

This should make the script to let go your processor for a while. (10 seconds to be exact)